# Swift sender.setTitle code didn't visible?

Tags: ios, swift

I have question about sender title. I have a button and I want to change title according to some condition. In this point I made sender.setTitle() code but title appear only  like 0.5 second. Its not visible let me say more clear. How can I solve it? 
Here my code:

```
    @objc func handleExpandCloseForAlim(sender: UIButton) {


    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        if keys[0] == 0 {
            sender.setTitle("titlesample", for: .normal)
            keys[0] = 1
        }else{
            keys[0] = 0
            sender.setTitle("titlesampleclose", for: .normal)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Here my header view code:

```
            let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 100))
        // code for adding centered title
        headerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 28))
        headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        headerLabel.text = "   Teslim Alınacağı Adres"
        headerLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        headerLabel.textAlignment = .left
        headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

        // code for adding button to right corner of section header
        let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:headerView.frame.size.width - 100, y:8, width:100, height:28))
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        button.tag = 1
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandCloseForAlim(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        headerView.addSubview(button)
        return headerView
```

Comment: So your title switches from "titlesample" to "titlesampleclose" and then back to "titlesample"after 0.5 seconds?

Comment: @Koen in fact, it doesn't seem exactly.

Comment: Please explain what the title is before and after you push the button. Did you step through the code to see what is going on?

Comment: @Koen I believe that I asked extremely understandable that I have found the answer. Please read more carefully.

Comment: @swift2: StaclOverflow is a place of volunteers and everyone is just trying to be helpful and asking for clarifications if they think something is not explained enough. Final goal is to get to an answer in a collaborative way. Something may be clear to you, but not to others. I understand that English is not your first language (it is not mine either), so we should be patient with each other. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @Koen Of course, we have to understand. Our common point is programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic part in the code above is that you are reloading your tableview in the **handleExpandCloseForAlim**. Since your tableView is reloaded, it will invoke **viewForHeaderInSection** function in your tableView from where you are returning a headerView with no title. That's why your label is getting disappeared.

You can solve this by having your button label as a field in your viewcontroller may be. Sample code may be like the one follows.

```
class YourViewController: UITableViewController {
    var buttonLabel: String = "titlesampleclose"
    .......
}
```

```
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 100))
        // code for adding centered title
        headerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray

        .........
        .........

        button.setTitle(buttonLabel,for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleExpandCloseForAlim(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        headerView.addSubview(button)
        return headerView
```

```
@objc func handleExpandCloseForAlim(sender: UIButton) {


    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        if keys[0] == 0 {
            self.buttonLabel = "titlesample"
            keys[0] = 1
        }else{
            keys[0] = 0
            self.buttonLabel = "titlesampleclose"
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps.